# A generalization of Galois connections

Tags: galois-theory, relations, order-theory

Let $f(x)\ast y \Leftrightarrow x\ast g(y)$ for some binary relation $\ast$ and functions $f$ and $g$. This is a generalization of Galois connections.

Are things like this studied before?

Note that in my theory $\ast$ is always a symmetric relation (except of the case when this is a Galois connection, and thus $\ast$ is a partial order).

Because it is symmetric, the formula can be rewritten: $f(x)\ast y \Leftrightarrow g(y)\ast x$ (or $y\ast f(x) \Leftrightarrow x\ast g(y)$).

Answer (score 0):

an adjunction in a groupoid.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors for the definition of adjunction and there are notes about how they generalize galois connections

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I am yet not strong in category theory. Particularly how is the relation $\ast$ related with an adjunction?

Comment: what is this nonsense?

Comment: abstract nonsense

Comment: I don't ask for any generalization of Galois connections, but namely where the order is replaced with a non-order relation. Your reference to adjoint functors seems unrelated. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: yeah ignore that, I just added that because they deleted my post without it